# Tinymce issue with firefox browser

Tags: asp.net-mvc, firefox, tinymce

I am using Tinymce version  4.0.12 and firefox version 29.0.1, .net 4.0, mvc 4.0, VS 2012
I am facing the issue with Tinymce editor and firefox. when reloading screen, it shows rendered html e. g.

hi

in editor for fraction of seconds only in firefox browser. whereas Other part of screen loads normally. In other browsers like IE, Chrome it works perfectly fine.
Following is my code to initialise tinymce editor.

```
{
        tinyMCE.baseURL = GetNewEmailURL() + "scripts/tinymce/js/tinymce";
        tinyMCE.init({
            menubar: false,
            mode: 'none',
            submit_patch: false,
            add_form_submit_trigger: false,
            selector: '#tinyMceForViewMail',
            statusbar: false,
            plugins: 'noneditable',
            toolbar: false,
            readonly: true,
            setup: function (editor) {
                editor.on('init', function () {
                    $("#" + this.id + "_ifr").height(window.screen.height - $("#TopMenuContainer").height() - $("#breadcrumbs").height() - $("#subject").height() - $("#MailHeader").height() - $("#Attachment").height() - 276);
                });

            }
        });
    }
```

I have tried with different attributed but no success. Please please help me out with this.

Answer (score 1):

I guess no one else faced such issue. So I am answering my own question :).
Well after many trial and errors finally got the solution.

Problem was TinyMc script and other scripts were taking time to load. Thus textarea with rendered html was displayed for some seconds. This textarea is to which i am binding TinyMc control. I had found two solution(felt like hitting jackpot :P).

1. Set visibility of textarea hidden.
   or
2. Moved all Jquery files and css in bundle config, so it gets loaded beforehand and so avoid any delays in loading tinyMc.

I guess 2nd solution is more appropriate.

Happy Coding ..